# How can I view the 95% CIs calculated from a ggcompetingrisks model that uses a cuminc object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I created a cuminc object and can print the estimates and variances directly in my console. I then used ggcompetingrisks to create a plot, and used the option conf.int = TRUE to plot the confidence intervals. However, I can't find the values of the confidence intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confidence bounds are not saved in the output. Fortunately it's easy to calculate them manually. Just extract `est` and `std` from `plot$data` and calculate `est+1.96*std` and `est-1.96*std`, replacing 1.96 with other z-values for other confidence limits.

```r
library(survminer)
library(cmprsk)
set.seed(2)
ss <- rexp(100)
gg <- factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),1:3,c('BRCA','LUNG','OV'))
cc <- factor(sample(0:2,100,replace=TRUE),0:2,c('no event', 'death', 'progression'))
strt <- sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)
fit <- cmprsk::cuminc(ss,cc,gg,strt)
plot <- ggcompetingrisks(fit, conf.int = TRUE)
plot
```

[image]

```r
# Calculate confidence bounds manually
dat <- plot$data
dat$ymax <- dat$est + 1.96*dat$std
dat$ymin <- dat$est - 1.96*dat$std
head(dat)
#>        time        est         var          name event group        std
#> 1 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000 BRCA no event    no  BRCA 0.00000000
#> 2 0.2731330 0.00000000 0.000000000 BRCA no event    no  BRCA 0.00000000
#> 3 0.2731330 0.03448276 0.001202639 BRCA no event    no  BRCA 0.03467908
#> 4 0.3312168 0.03448276 0.001202639 BRCA no event    no  BRCA 0.03467908
#> 5 0.3312168 0.06896552 0.002321886 BRCA no event    no  BRCA 0.04818595
#> 6 0.7388502 0.06896552 0.002321886 BRCA no event    no  BRCA 0.04818595
#>        ymax        ymin
#> 1 0.0000000  0.00000000
#> 2 0.0000000  0.00000000
#> 3 0.1024538 -0.03348824
#> 4 0.1024538 -0.03348824
#> 5 0.1634100 -0.02547895
#> 6 0.1634100 -0.02547895

# Plot to confirm they match
ggcompetingrisks(fit, conf.int = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(data = dat, 
              mapping = aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, x = time,
                            fill = event),
              alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how long I was working on this...